# Swift Keychain SecItemCopyMatching() returns errSecItemNotFound after changing kSecAttrAccessible Attribute

Tags: ios, swift, keychain, deprecation-warning

My app stores a user's license key as a keychain item.

I have set the `kSecAttrAccessible` attribute to `kSecAttrAccessibleAlwaysThisDeviceOnly` in the past, but since this was deprecated in iOS 12, I now want to change it to `kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly` in the latest app update.

Keychain items written with the new attribute can be read with the new attribute. Keychain items written in older app versions using the old attribute however cannot be read with the new attribute — `SecItemCopyMatching()` returns `errSecItemNotFound`.

It does work the other way around though: Items written to the keychain with the `kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly` attribute could be read using the `kSecAttrAccessibleAlwaysThisDeviceOnly`.

Is this expected behaviour? And is there a more elegant way to get rid of the deprecation than to delete and rewrite the keychain entries with an intermediate cleanup routine that would have to use deprecated attribute too?

Comment: I'm not quite clear why you're searching based on the accessible. Do you need to do that? Typically you write the accessible attribute, and occasionally you might read it, but why would you query on it?

Comment: So I had the misconception that I needed to state `kSecAttrAccessible` for read _and_ write operations. I just leave it away in the read operations and everything works. Thanks Rob!